# Pandas is not aggregating a simple data frame correctly. Is it a bug, or my platform?

Tags: python, pandas

I am stumped, because Pandas is not responding as expected. With this simple data frame:

```
food_data = {
    "Item": ["Banana", "Cucumber", "Orange", "Tomato", "Watermelon"],
    "Type": ["Fruit", "Vegetable", "Fruit", "Vegetable", "Fruit"],
    "Price": [0.99, 1.25, 0.25, 0.33, 3.00]
}

supermarket = pd.DataFrame(data = food_data)
```

I am getting an error when performing simple aggregations:

```
groups = supermarket.groupby("Type")
groups.mean()
```

This is the error output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py:1490, in GroupBy._cython_agg_general..array_func(values)
   1489 try:
-> 1490     result = self.grouper._cython_operation(
   1491         "aggregate",
   1492         values,
   1493         how,
   1494         axis=data.ndim - 1,
   1495         min_count=min_count,
   1496         **kwargs,
   1497     )
   1498 except NotImplementedError:
   1499     # generally if we have numeric_only=False
   1500     # and non-applicable functions
   1501     # try to python agg
   1502     # TODO: shouldn't min_count matter?

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py:959, in BaseGrouper._cython_operation(self, kind, values, how, axis, min_count, **kwargs)
    958 ngroups = self.ngroups
--> 959 return cy_op.cython_operation(
    960     values=values,
    961     axis=axis,
    962     min_count=min_count,
    963     comp_ids=ids,
...
   1698             # e.g. "foo"
-> 1699             raise TypeError(f"Could not convert {x} to numeric") from err
   1700 return x

TypeError: Could not convert BananaOrangeWatermelon to numeric
```

Is it possible that such a simple case wasn't caught in testing?

I am running Python 3.10.11 with Pandas 2.0.3.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for wasting everyone's time. After checking the Pandas API, yes, this is new behavior since 2.0.0.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html

Versus 1.5.2, where it applied the aggregation only to float, int, and bool columns:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd

food_data = {
    "Item": ["Banana", "Cucumber", "Orange", "Tomato", "Watermelon"],
    "Type": ["Fruit", "Vegetable", "Fruit", "Vegetable", "Fruit"],
    "Price": [0.99, 1.25, 0.25, 0.33, 3.00]
}

supermarket = pd.DataFrame(data=food_data)

groups = supermarket.groupby("Type")
mean_price = groups["Price"].mean()

print(mean_price)
```

You calculate the mean price within each group by accessing the "Price" column and applying the `mean()` function to it.

Output:

```
Type
Fruit        1.413333
Vegetable    0.790000
Name: Price, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Is this relatively new behavior? I am reviewing a book "Pandas in Action" by Boris Pashkaver, and both in the book and in my prior work with Pandas, the aggregation function was able to only pick the numeric columns. Right now it's being applied to all columns (including the strings, which get concatenated).


E.g., try ```groups.sum()```